# Figuring out if SQL Server database needs to be defragmented

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am tasked with looking at if a database in SQL Server 2014 needs to be defragmented.  I ran DBCC SHOWCONTIG but am having trouble interpreting the results.

```
use databasename;
GO  
DBCC SHOWCONTIG ('Table');  
GO
```

The results are:

```
DBCC SHOWCONTIG scanning 'Table' table...
Table: 'Table' (802206008); index ID: 1, database ID: 20
TABLE level scan performed.
- Pages Scanned................................: 2239
- Extents Scanned..............................: 280
- Extent Switches..............................: 279
- Avg. Pages per Extent........................: 8.0
- Scan Density [Best Count:Actual Count].......: 100.00% [280:280]
- Logical Scan Fragmentation ..................: 0.00%
- Extent Scan Fragmentation ...................: 31.79%
- Avg. Bytes Free per Page.....................: 366.8
- Avg. Page Density (full).....................: 95.47%
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
```

Questions:

1. What do the percentages above mean? (like the difference between logical and extent scan fragmentation).
2. What percentage do I need to check and what value indicates the disk needs to be defragmented?

Comment: A lot of people use https://ola.hallengren.com just because their script has already worked most of this out for you

Comment: Is your underlying storage RAIDed or hosted on a shared storage device/solution such as a DAS or SAN?

Comment: Is this workload mostly reading lots of rows keyed on the table's clustered index, or single-row reads?

Answer (score 0):

**Logical Scan Fragmentation**  Percentage of out-of-order pages returned from scanning the leaf pages of an index. This number is not relevant to heaps. An out-of-order page is a page for which the next physical page allocated to the index is not the page pointed to by the next-page pointer in the current leaf page.

**Extent Scan Fragmentation**   Percentage of out-of-order extents in scanning the leaf pages of an index. This number is not relevant to heaps. An out-of-order extent is one for which the extent that contains the current page for an index is not physically the next extent after the extent that contains the previous page for an index.

Did you try this page: [DBCC SHOWCONTIG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-showcontig-transact-sql)?

Comment: Yes but what does that really mean? still trying to understand it

Comment: What is an extent? New to this

Comment: Understanding pages and extents: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190969%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396.